# Hibernate Native SQL Query retrieving multiple entities in join

Tags: java, hibernate, native-sql

Referencing with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17210746/2186777) answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186806/hibernate-native-sql-query-retrieving-entities-and-collections/17210746) correlated thread,
the trick posted by ehrhardt works fine.

But, what I have to do if I have to join with multiple entities? for example:

```
List<Person> peopleWithBooks = session.createSQLQuery(
    "select {p.*}, {b.*}, {m.*} from person p, book b, magazine m where <complicated join>")
        .addEntity("p", Person.class)
        .addJoin("b", "p.books")
        .addJoin("m", "p.magazines")
        .addEntity("p", Person.class)
        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
        .list();
```

Hibernate aggregates right the first join, but not the second (magazine entities are not grouped).

There are any tricks or there is a limit to join with only one correlated entity?
And if I have to join with entities that have sub entities? (my goal is to retrieve all selected data with only one custom query)

Comment: No anyone have to say something about?