# hibernate native query mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to make a native named query.I saw the link

[result-set-mapping-complex-mappings](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-complex-mappings/)

```
<sql-result-set-mapping name="BookAuthorMappingXml">
   <entity-result entity-class="org.thoughts.on.java.jpa.model.Author">
    <field-result name="id" column="authorId"/>
    <field-result name="firstName" column="firstName"/>
    <field-result name="lastName" column="lastName"/>
    <field-result name="version" column="authorVersion"/>
</entity-result>

   <entity-result entity-class="org.thoughts.on.java.jpa.model.Book">
       <field-result name="id" column="id"/>
       <field-result name="title" column="title"/>
       <field-result name="author" column="author_id"/>
       <field-result name="version" column="version"/>
   </entity-result>
</sql-result-set-mapping>
```

the number of columns i have is more than 20.Is there is way to map all columns in one go

I am using hibernate 4.2

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/17210746/2646526?

Comment: yes but using named queries and method like defined in question

Comment: something like this? https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-persistence/jbpm-persistence-jpa/src/main/resources/META-INF/JBPMorm.xml

Comment: You could create a new Entity class that has all the fields you want and not bother describing each fieldresult. That way instead of an `Object[]` each row would give you a well-described class you won't even have to typecast.

Comment: I dont want to create a new entity class as the number of fields are too many and this will make me change the entire references

Comment: Well, then the answer to your question is "no". There is no short way to do it. You'll have to describe it in the long and harder to maintain way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is an hibernate mapping auto generation. 
You can follow the blog from mkyong

https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/