# Hibernate native SQL query - how to get distinct root entities with eagerly initialized one-to-many association

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, eager-loading, resulttransformer

I have two entities `Dept` and `Emp` (real case changed and minimized). There is 1:n association between them, i.e. properties `Dept.empList` and `Emp.dept` exist with respective annotations. I want to get `List<Dept>` whose elements are distinct and have collection `empList` eagerly initialized, using native SQL query.

```java
session.createSQLQuery("select {d.*}, {e.*} from dept d join emp e on d.id = e.dept_id")
        .addEntity("d", Dept.class)
        .addJoin("e", "d.empList")
        //.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
        .list();
```

This query returns `List<Object[2]>` with instances of `Dept`, `Emp` (in that order) in the array and field `Dept.empList` properly initialized. That's ok.

To get distinct `Dept`s, I thought setting transformer `DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY` (uncommenting the line) would be enough. Unfortunately, the `DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer` is based on `RootEntityResultTransformer` which treats the last element in tuple as root entity (it's hardwired). Since the order of entities is determined by sequence of `addEntity`, `addJoin` calls, the transformer mistakenly treats `Emp` as root entity and returns list with all `Emp`s of all `Dept`s.

**Is there any clean way how to make Hibernate recognized the `Dept` as root entity, even though it is not last in entity list?**

*Note 1:* I tried to switch order to `.addJoin("e", "d.empList").addEntity("d", Dept.class)`. Does not work since `d.empList` requires `d` defined. Fails on `HibernateSystemException : Could not determine fetch owner` somewhere in Hibernate internals (`org.hibernate.loader.Loader`).

*Note 2:* I tried to define order as `.addEntity("e", Emp.class).addJoin("d", "e.dept")`. This seemingly works but the association is actually filled only from the "many" side. Hence the collection `Dept.empList` is some uninitialized proxy until requested, which invokes explicit SQL query and thus does not utilize the join in my query.

*Note 3:* The custom transformer looking for hard-wired index works:

```java
        .setResultTransformer(new BasicTransformerAdapter() {
            public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
                return tuple[0];
            }
            public List transformList(List list) {
                return DistinctResultTransformer.INSTANCE.transformList( list );
            }
        })
```

though I'm hesitant to accept such easy task could have such complicated solution.

Hibernate version: 3.6.10 (I know - legacy project :-) though I looked into source code of latest version and seems the key points don't differ).

Answer (score 0):

Finally found https://stackoverflow.com/a/17210746/653539 - make duplicate call of `.addEntity` to force root entity on the end of list:

```java
    .addEntity("d", Dept.class)
    .addJoin("e", "d.empList")
    .addEntity("d", Dept.class)
```

It's still workaround but cleaner than mine and - based on 36 upvotes - it seems as idiomatic solution.